# Relative Date: 1/1/1981 01:01:01 - 1/1/1980 = 1y 366d ect, want 1y 1d etc

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date, datetime, time

I am doing some enhancements of a date library which already returns differences in date units as expressed in the title of this question. I want it to return relative units. I've written some code, but it feels like I am working from the wrong end of the math.

Note: Forget about leap years and other DateTime intricacies. This is for a non-exacting application.

Here is the code under consideration.

```
// get ms between UTC dates and make into "difference" date
var iDiffMS = dt2.valueOf() - dt1.valueOf();
var dtDiff = new Date(iDiffMS);

// calc various diffs
var nYears  = dt2.getUTCFullYear() - dt1.getUTCFullYear();
var nMonths = dt2.getUTCMonth() - dt1.getUTCMonth() + (nYears!=0 ? nYears*12 : 0);
var nQuarters = parseInt(nMonths / 3);  //<<-- different than VBScript, which watches rollover not completion

// these are in absolute terms, ie totals of unit differences, 1/2/1981 - 1/1/1980 = 1y 366d
var nMilliseconds = iDiffMS;
var nSeconds = parseInt(iDiffMS / 1000);
var nMinutes = parseInt(nSeconds / 60);
var nHours = parseInt(nMinutes / 60);
var nDays  = parseInt(nHours / 24); // <-- now fixed for DST switch days
var nWeeks = parseInt(nDays / 7);
// save absolutes
var nYears0=nYears;
var nMonths0=nMonths;
var nQuarters0=nQuarters;
var nWeeks0=nWeeks;
var nDays0=nDays;
var nHours0=nHours;
var nMinutes0=nMinutes;
var nSeconds0=nSeconds;

// HERE! go from absolute to relative, 1/2/1981 - 1/1/1980 = 1y 1d etc, not 1y 366d etc
nQuarters     -=nYears0*4;
nMonths       -=nYears0*12;
nWeeks        -=parseInt((nYears0*52)+(nMonths0*(365.25/52)));
nCalWeeks     -=parseInt((nYears0*52)+(nMonths0*(365.25/52)));
nQuarters     -=nYears0*4;
nDays         -=parseInt((nYears0*365.25)               +(nMonths*(365.25/12)));
nHours        -=parseInt((nYears0*365.25*24)            +(nMonths*(365.25/12*24))           +(nDays*24));
nMinutes      -=parseInt((nYears0*365.25*24*60)         +(nMonths*(365.25/12*24*60))        +(nDays*24*60)         +(nHours*60));
nSeconds      -=parseInt((nYears0*365.25*24*60*60)      +(nMonths*(365.25/12*24*60*60))     +(nDays*24*60*60)      +(nHours*60*60)      +(nMinutes*60));
nMilliseconds -=parseInt((nYears0*365.25*24*60*60*1000) +(nMonths*(365.25/12*24*60*60*1000))+(nDays*24*60*60*1000) +(nHours*60*60*1000) +(nMinutes*60*1000) + (nSeconds*1000));
// END
```

Comment: In your desired format, what's the correct answer for 3/3/1981 - 1/1/1980?  Do you want '1 year, 2 months, 2 days'?

Comment: Yes, just take the difference in miliseconds (after 1970) and transform it back

Comment: Yes, 1 year, 2 months, 2 days, x hours, etc

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement this by working from larger units to smaller units, but it's probably easier to work from small to large because you don't have to multiply the factors in advance. For example, you don't have to figure out ahead of time that a day is 24*60*60*1000 milliseconds. Instead, you can build up the factors as you go along from the smallest unit to the largest unit.

In the first step, you know that you have to divide the number of milliseconds by 1000 to get the number of seconds. In the second step, you divide the seconds by 60 to get the number of minutes. Next, you divide by 60 to get the hours. Next, you divide by 24 to get the days.

To ensure that you're not double-counting units, you can use the modulo operator, `%`. For example, if the number of minutes is 135, calculate `135 % 60` to get `15`, which is the minutes left over after subtracting the whole hours. In general, before displaying the number of current units, you want to take the modulo with respect to the next greater unit.

The following script implements this approach.

```js
function getDifferenceInWords(dateStart, dateEnd) {
  var delta = dateEnd.valueOf() - dateStart.valueOf();
  if (delta < 0) {
    var describe = "earlier";
    delta = -delta;
  } else {
    var describe = "later";
  }
  var units = [{ name: 'second', multiple: 1000 },  
               { name: 'minute', multiple: 60 },    
               { name: 'hour', multiple: 60 },    
               { name: 'day', multiple: 24 },    
               { name: 'week', multiple: 7 },     
               { name: 'quarter', multiple: 13 },
               { name: 'year', multiple: 4 }],
      divisor = 1,
      parts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < units.length; ++i) {
    var unit = units[i];
    divisor *= unit.multiple;
    if (divisor > delta) {
      break;
    }
    var count = Math.floor(delta / divisor);
    if (i+1 < units.length) {
      count %= units[i+1].multiple;
    }
    if (count != 0) {
      parts.push(count + ' ' + unit.name + (count == 1 ? '' : 's'));
    }
  }
  parts.reverse();
  return parts.join(', ') + ' ' + describe;
}

var dateStart = new Date('January 1, 1995 09:01:30'),
    dateEnd = new Date('May 1, 2015 23:05:15');

document.write(getDifferenceInWords(dateStart, dateEnd));
```

You can adjust the code to your liking by abbreviating the unit names or changing the sequence of units.

For example, you might want to introduce months as an intermediate unit between weeks and quarters if you can settle on a fixed ratio of months to weeks. I prefer to leave out month units because different months have different lengths, which leads to inconsistent results depending on what dates you're dealing with.

Another way to modify the units might be to add decades, centuries, and millennia. As long as you follow the pattern of the `units` data structure, where each unit is a fixed multiple of the previous unit, you can't go wrong.

Comment: I like that approach, though it mixes the string output with the calculations. I am sure that the month thing can be worked out with some kind of back calculation, but my brain isn't up to it right now.

Comment: The strings do not affect the calculations at all. I am merely prettifying the output by forming plural unit names and leaving out zero unit counts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I was looking for, notice how it changes once you get down to the hours. Continuing on the `t1-=` path would lead to time errors due to leap years. Also, months have to be calculated in this manner to rectify leaps. I suspect a problem with the `weeks` calculation though.

```
var d1=new Date('1/1/1980 00:00:00:000');
var d2=new Date('2/8/1981 01:01:01:001');
//BUG "1y 1m 1w 1d 23h 59mins 59secs 999ms" should be 0d
//var d2=new Date('2/7/1981 23:59:59:999'); 

var t1=d2.valueOf() - d1.valueOf();
console.log(t1);
var nYears= parseInt(t1/(1000*60*60*24*365.25));
t1-=nYears*(1000*60*60*24*365.25);
var s='';
s+=nYears+'y';
var nMonths=d2.getUTCMonth() - d1.getUTCMonth();
nMonths=nMonths>0?nMonths:nMonths+12;
s+=' '+nMonths+'m'
t1-=nMonths*1000*60*60*24*(365.25/12);
var nWeeks=parseInt(t1/(1000*60*60*24*7));
s+=' '+nWeeks+'w'
t1-=nWeeks*(1000*60*60*24*7);
var nDays=parseInt(t1/(1000*60*60*24));
s+=' '+nDays+'d'
t1-=nDays*(1000*60*60*24);
var nHours=d2.getHours()-d1.getHours();
s+=' '+nHours+'h';
var nMinutes=d2.getMinutes()-d1.getMinutes();
s+=' '+nMinutes+'mins';
var nSeconds=d2.getSeconds()-d1.getSeconds();
s+=' '+nSeconds+'secs';
var nMilliseconds=d2.getMilliseconds()-d1.getMilliseconds();
s+=' '+nMilliseconds+'ms';
//console.log(d1.getHours());
console.log(s); //"1y 1m 1w 1d 1h 1mins 1secs 1ms"
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. Try it with `var d1 = new Date('12/25/1980 10:10:00:000');
var d2 = new Date('2/8/1981 01:01:01:001');`

Comment: Still doesn't work. If you want to use the built-in `get...()` functions, you have to make sure you're proceeding from the past to the future or from the future to the past. Or you can avoid all this and just use arithmetic operations as I showed in my answer.

Comment: You ignored the hours and minutes in my example. Also, you haven't really fixed the problem with months. Consider these time spans: `4/25/1980` to `5/5/1980`, `4/5/1980` to `4/25/1980`, `4/25/1979` to `4/5/1980`. Do you see what's happening? Now throw hours and minutes into the mix and see the further complications. What you need is a systematic approach. You must proceed strictly in one direction along the arrow of time.